# Automated email copied recipient limit

Tags: google-apps-script, google-workspace

I am trying to copy recipients on automatic birthday emails and it's saying I've exceeded the recipient limit.  I pieced together code I found to make this work but I can't tell from this part where the limit is, if I can up the limit.

```
var ccRecipients = [];
for (var i = 0; i < emailData.length; i++) {
var email = emailData[i][0];
if (email !== "") {
ccRecipients.push(email);
```

Answer (score 1):

https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/quotas

The limit is 100 email recipients per day (if you are using a free account). This coded on Googles side, not yours.

Comment: My recipients is only 86 though.  Is BCC a different limit?

Comment: Yes but they measure it by a rate so if you exceed the rate for a short period of time you may still exceed the limit and you will have to wait a while before you can try again